# Does valence electrons have restricted spin?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, physical-chemistry

For a valence electron in Antimony Sb with the electron configuration:

$Kr(5s)^2(4d)^{10}(5p)^3$

The 3 valence electrons have the quantum numbers $n=5,l=1,m=1$, resulting in the following possibilities for $(n,l,m_l,m_s)$

$(5,1,-1,-\frac{1}{2});(5,1,-1,\frac{1}{2});(5,1,1,-\frac{1}{2});(5,1,1,\frac{1}{2});(5,1,0,-\frac{1}{2});(5,1,0,\frac{1}{2})$

$(5,0,0,-\frac{1}{2});(5,0,0,\frac{1}{2})$

Then looking at the actual quantum numbers of Sb (from a former exam) it is given as:

$(5,1,-1,\frac{1}{2});(5,1,1,\frac{1}{2});(5,1,0,\frac{1}{2})$

$(5,0,0,-\frac{1}{2});(5,0,0,\frac{1}{2})$

There did the quantum sets with $l=1$ and $m_s=-\frac{1}{2}$ go? When I look at the valence electrons in Kr the set is **with** $l=1$ and $m_s=-\frac{1}{2}$:

$(4,1,-1,-\frac{1}{2});(4,1,-1,\frac{1}{2});(4,1,1,-\frac{1}{2});(4,1,1,\frac{1}{2});(4,1,0,-\frac{1}{2});(4,1,0,\frac{1}{2})$

$(4,0,0,-\frac{1}{2});(4,0,0,\frac{1}{2})$

Summing up the question: Why can the valence electrons in Kr have $l=1$ and $m_s=-\frac{1}{2}$ and the ones in Sb not? Perhaps it is a misstake in the exam?

Comment: in lack of answers I have posted a similar question on the **chemistry stackexchange** if I get answer in that forum i'll post it here.